Change of cell proportions or differential expression?
Suppose bulk RNA-Seq of two conditions is given, together with the gene-expression profile typical of various cell types. A person wants to compare the cell type proportions between the two conditions.
Cell type proportions can be deconvoluted from bulk data (more easily so with a reference) eg via CibersortX.

Is it possible to distinguish between a change in cell type proportions (the cell types composition is different between the two conditions) and a change in gene expression (both conditions have the same cell types, but the gene expression pattern has changed between the conditions ) ?

How is it possible conceptually?



I think that you are more likely to get a helpful answer at Bioinformatics Stack Exchange or Biostars or some other site more focused on biology. Some genes are expressed only in specific cell types, which might provide a basis for parceling out the composition/expression problem. Your question seems too far away from statistics per se to be on-topic on this site, however. The problem you've identified is a reason that single-cell RNAseq is increasingly popular.

Following EdM's advice, crossposted at https://www.biostars.org/p/9600211/
